# System.IO.Abstractions Limitations

Tags: c#, .net

I've been recently using [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions) in order to mock to filesystem and be able to write tests. Regular operations like reading, writing from the file work just fine. However, trying to set a lock on a file is not taken into consideration. Also trying to use a stream writer against a file stream opened exclusively for read access succeeds.

Not sure if the functionality just isn't there or if I'm missing something. Anyone else came across this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this behavior is not implemented. And it is not considered to be implemented:  [see here](https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions/issues/71#issuecomment-37710581).
However pull requests are always welcome ;)